# Repeated negation (!) operators in bash do not negate each other

Tags: bash, negation

So this is more an oddity I've come up against than something I really want to use. But I found something I didn't understand with the bash extended test syntax.

Check this out (included my shell version in case it matters):

```
34>$SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
35>[ ! -d /tmp ] && echo Hi
36>[ ! ! -d /tmp ] && echo Hi
Hi
37>[[ ! -d /tmp ]] && echo Hi
38>[[ ! ! -d /tmp ]] && echo Hi
39>
```

OK, so lines 35 and 36, using the normal test, operate as I expect. The single bang doesn't print a line (because /tmp exists), and the double bang does.

Line 37, using extended bash syntax, also doesn't print anything, as I would expect. But line 38 doesn't either! This is surprising to me; it indicates that the directory doesn't exist, but also doesn't not exist?

Searching for information on this has been frustrating. Am I missing something here? An unmentioned syntax error? I just want to understand why this happens.

Comment: If you want this to be well-defined, move the `!`s outside. `! ! [[ -d /tmp ]]` relies only on behavior that's actually part of the test suite for the shell, whereas the historical understanding of `test` behavior referenced in answer E1 in the FAQ in bash's codebase does not require multiple `!`s *inside* a single test to be valid (or to have any other specific/particular behavior, making the result at hand here as legitimate as any other -- ain't undefined behavior fun?).

Comment: I'm reading E1 as describing why `!` doesn't bind as tightly as `-o`, nothing more. `[[ ! ! -d /tmp ]]` failing just looks like a bug to me; `[[ ! (! -d /tmp) ]]` works correctly.

Comment: To clarify, I don't WANT to ever actually use this code. I was just curious to understand why it behaved like it does. :)

Comment: I can reproduce this issue in bash 4.4.18(1)-release. Interestingly, `ksh` does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the use of a flag in the BASH code which is not toggled in this particular case, only the first instance of `!` matters, unless brackets are separating them.

To find this out, first I took a look at the [Bash(1) Man Page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Reserved Words
>
> Reserved words are words that have a special meaning to the shell. [...] words are recognized as reserved when unquoted and either the first word of a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR below) or the third word of a case or for command

Which hints to the usage of the `!` reserved word.

However, this doesn't really explain it very well. So I took a look at the [source code (version 4.4.18) for Bash](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/).

It looks like `command.h` contains a flag which is set for a command, when it detects the `!` symbol:

```
#define CMD_INVERT_RETURN  0x04 /* Invert the exit value. */
```

This is used several times in the `execute_cmd.c` file:

```
invert = (command->flags & CMD_INVERT_RETURN) != 0;
```

But this file seems to just check for the presence of the flag. I believe the parsing of it is done in another file.

On line 4507 of `parse.y`, we can see that it seems to just be set, not toggled. This means that it doesn't matter how many occurrences of BANG (`!`) there is, it'll only set the flag once.

```
else if (tok == BANG || (tok == WORD && (yylval.word->word[0] == '!' && yylval.word->word[1] == '\0'))) {
  if (tok == WORD)
dispose_word (yylval.word); /* not needed */
  term = cond_term ();
  if (term)
term->flags |= CMD_INVERT_RETURN;
}
```

I find this behaviour strange, since later in the code, there is support for toggling this value, on line 1201 of `parse.y`, which relates to pipelines (formatted for readability)

```
pipeline_command: pipeline
{ $$ = $1; }            
    | BANG pipeline_command {
        if ($2)
            $2->flags ^= CMD_INVERT_RETURN; /* toggle */
        $$ = $2;
    }
```

Comment: That certainly matches what the behavior is, but it seems weird. I don't think I'd ever expect any programming language to make `! ! true` return `false`, and to not mention it in extended test syntax documentation, if it is a deliberate choice, seems unhelpful